# Flatten List of Objects in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework (DRF) and am trying to create a custom serializer that flattens a list of objects to a list of strings. I have the following definitions:

Models:

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    crn = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    action = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.email} - {self.crn}"


class Qualification(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"


class MyUserQualification(models.Model):
    myuser = models.ForeignKey(
        MyUser, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="qualifications"
    )
    qualification = models.ForeignKey(Qualification, on_delete=CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} - {self.version}"
```

Serializers:

```
class MyUserQualificationBulkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.CharField(source="qualification.id")

    class Meta:
        model = myUserQualification
        fields = ["id"]


class BulkQualificationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    qualifications = MyUserQualificationBulkSerializer(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = myUser
        fields = ["qualifications"]
```

Views:

```
class MyUserDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    lookup_field = "email"
    queryset = MyUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BulkQualificationSerializer
```

When I get my view, I get something like this:

```
"qualifications": [
        {
            "id": "70b019bc-23c3-46e1-9d9f-5f30e10b5c2e"
        },
        {
            "id": "70b019bc-23c3-46e1-9d9f-5f30e10b5c2e"
        },
        {
            "id": "aa9ef90c-69c4-43ea-ab5c-10fac32160f6"
        },
        {
            "id": "e3b0fc09-f143-4801-81dd-6624ad07a590"
        },
        {
            "id": "937f8253-ae58-4059-9ae5-a9a98e41bf72"
        },
        {
            "id": "b646765f-0416-4c61-9f8f-3cefe7f10ff7"
        },
        {
            "id": "94a5b2a4-2470-47b9-aa7d-a59f7f4a5383"
        }
    ]
```

What I am trying to do is flatten the view returned so it is just a list of ids (which are a charField) as opposed to a list of objects with the curly braces.

How can I flatten my view to this?:

```
"qualifications": [
            "70b019bc-23c3-46e1-9d9f-5f30e10b5c2e",
            "70b019bc-23c3-46e1-9d9f-5f30e10b5c2e",
            "aa9ef90c-69c4-43ea-ab5c-10fac32160f6",
            "e3b0fc09-f143-4801-81dd-6624ad07a590",
            "937f8253-ae58-4059-9ae5-a9a98e41bf72",
            "b646765f-0416-4c61-9f8f-3cefe7f10ff7",
            "94a5b2a4-2470-47b9-aa7d-a59f7f4a5383",
    ]
```

Comment: Your flattened data is not a valid json? Or did you just want the ids without `"id":`?

Comment: Apologies you are correct, just the ids without the `id:` (I fumbled my copy paste). I have edited the original question now.

Comment: You can do this by removing the declaration `qualifications = MyUserQualificationBulkSerializer(..` in `BulkQualificationSerializer`. Is that an option?

Comment: Thank you, I managed to sort it out removing the thing as you said and writing a custom serializer method.

Comment: Glad to help. Have fun!